# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 : alamofire post

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am using xcode 7.3 with swift 2.3. For making network connection I am using 'Alamofire','~> 3.4.1'.  I am facing no problem till I execute archive option. I am getting and Xcode marked this error marked at --->

**Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**

```
class func post(url: String, headers:[String: String], parameters:[String: AnyObject], success:(AnyObject)->(), failure:(AnyObject)->()) -> () {
--->        Alamofire.request(.POST,
            url,
            headers:headers,
            parameters:parameters,encoding:.URL)
            .debugLog()
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in

                response.debugLog() 
                switch response.result{
                case .Success(_):
                    //print(response)
                    let httpResponseBody = response.result.value! as String
                    success(httpResponseBody)

                case .Failure(_):
                    let error = response.result.error
                    //print(error)
                    failure(error!)


                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 4 hours debugging for the cause of error I finally figure out that  This piece of code  was causing problem.

`extension Request {
    public func debugLog() -> Self {
        //#if DEBUG
        debugPrint(self)
        //#endif
        return self
    }
}`

then i comment out .debug() from

```
    class func post(url: String, headers:[String: String], parameters:[String: AnyObject], success:(AnyObject)->(), failure:(AnyObject)->()) -> () {
--->        Alamofire.request(.POST,
            url,
            headers:headers,
            parameters:parameters,encoding:.URL)
           // .debugLog()
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in

                response.debugLog() 
                switch response.result{
                case .Success(_):
                    //print(response)
                    let httpResponseBody = response.result.value! as String
                    success(httpResponseBody)

                case .Failure(_):
                    let error = response.result.error
                    //print(error)
                    failure(error!)


                }
        }
```